# Unit testing on an Angular app with Karma

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-runner, chai

So i'm quite new with test cases and I have a small questions (specific to my case).

I am currently developing an Angular app and started to do unit test with Karma (Mocha/Chai). 
The back end of this app is a node RESTful API.
So basically, the app is a bunch of controllers and services making some basic CRUD operations.

On creation of a new user for example, I handle the verification in the html form using angular's form directives. In the server side, there is also a verification on the object received.
So generally my functions on controllers are no more then things like:

```
create() {
  UserService.create(vm.newUser).then(callBackToDisplaySuccessOrErrorMessage); 
}
```

It will probably sounds silly, but i'm new in this domain (test cases) and i am a little bit confused, so my first question is:

**since the http calls are mocked, what is the point to do unit testing in app such as mine ?**

And my second question is :

**how to unit test basic app like in my case in a proper way ?**

Comment: The point of testing controllers is to check that your controller does call the expected service, with the expected arguments, and reacts to success/errors correctly. The point of unit testing the service is to check that it sends the expected HTTP request, with the correct URL and body, and transfers the success/error result correctly to its callers. But having unit tests doesn't mean that you shouldn't have integration (a.K;a. end to end) tests to verify that the app, as a whole, works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify your doubts:
1. Mocking is used to test the communication.
While writing spec for your controller who are more interested in verifying whether a call to userService.create is invoked with expected parameters or not. Similarly you will mock the response from service if any. So you have validated the functionality of Controller-communicating with- Service.

Now when you write spec for service, yes http calls are mocked, but still you are validating the http url, expected method to be invoked like GET, POST etc, parameters to be passed. You only mock the expected success/failure response and validate your handlers for the same.